# Understanding slicing of an array into a variable

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm a novice coder (in Python) and I have been given a code in matlab (I have 0 matlab experience). I have been able to translate most of the code, but I am stuck at a certain point. BROADLY the goal of the code is to do a fourier transform on data and then check if the result meets certain rules.

I'm providing a bit of the code leading up to the line where I'm confused

#fourier transform (I understand these steps)

```
num_rows = length(csvfilename);
Y = fft(csvfilename);
P1 = abs(Y).^2/num_rows;
```

#I don't understand this next line of code

```
P1_vec(1,:) = P1;
```

What does it mean to have P1 on the right hand side of the line? And what does (1,:) mean in Matlab?

Thank you! :)

I have tried to look on matlab guidance documents, and translations to python from matlab, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB doesn't really have 1D arrays, and you'll end up having 1xN or Nx1 matrices.

```
>> size([1,2,3])
ans =
     1     3
```

meaning you actually have the concept of transposing "1D" arrays in MATLAB.
Most of the slicing and vector operations are intentionally vague when it comes to tranposition of these vectors, and matlab will happily ignore the singular dimension whenever it makes sense.

```matlab
m = zeros(2,3);
m(1,:) = [1,2,3];   % assigns the first row of m to be the row vector [1,2,3]
m(2,:) = [4,5,6]';  % assigns the second row of m to be the column vector [4;5;6]
>> m
m =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```

as we can see, MATLAB ignores how the RHS is formed here.

So why would someone choose to construct

```
P_vec(1,:) = some_vector;
```

well it ensures that regardless of whether `some_vector`  is a 1 by N or a N by 1 matrix, P_vec will always be a 1 by N (what we normally would call a row vector)

I'd call this matlab sloppy code (not bothering to keep track of transposes), and in any language/library that does has support for actual 1D arrays (like numpy) this operation wouldn't be relevant as you can't transpose such arrays anyway.

Comment: That's really helpful - thank you very much! I believe that the person writing the code was a newer coder as well, so that mixed with the fact that I have no experience in matlab at all is not very fun!  But your answer has been very helpful :) I hope you have a nice day!

Comment: @JackieG You are welcome. Remember to accept the answer if you feel your question has been answered.